# Count number of friends in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to count all the user's added friends in their page profile. For example, here user 1 has 2 friends, so I want to display `Friends(2)`.

MY DB:

```
Table: mls_users
-------------------------------------------
id | username | password | name | surname |
 1      me        ****     Alex     Alex
 2     Ana       ******    Maria    Jade
 3    Diana       ****     Ladys    Becky
-------------------------------------------

Table: myfriends
-----------------------
id | myid | myfriends | <- my friends id
-----------------------
 1     1       2
 2     2       3
```

Here's the code I've tried so far.

```
<?php 
          include 'sql/db-conn.php';
          $myid = $_SESSION['user'];
          $frnd = $_GET['u'];
          $friend_count = mysqli_query($db,"
          SELECT * FROM `mls_users` U LEFT JOIN `myfriends` F on `f`.`myid` = $frnd AND CASE WHEN `F`.`myfriends` = $frnd THEN `F`.`myid` = $myid END where `U`.`id` != $myid");
          $mu = mysqli_num_rows($friend_count);
                     ?>
                    <h5 class="margin-b-10">Friends (<?php echo $mu;?>)</h5>
```

Comment: What do you want? Count the friends for a mls_users.id?

Comment: Yes @RaymondNijland

Comment: Note that your code is vulnerable to injection attacks. You should never pass user-supplied data directly into an SQL query.

Comment: Ok and whats the expected output?

Comment: the total number off all my friends

Comment: The answer is 1.

Comment: wOw super :)))) nice answer =))

Comment: I made your question easier to read. You should also explain why your code is not working. Otherwise this question is likely to get downvoted and ignored.

Comment: is not counting the corect numbers of all the "friends'" from my friends list that i have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very simple unless there is something you have left out about the design of the tables.

There is also no need to join the tables as the answer you want is entirely derived from myFriends.

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as count_friends FROM myFriends WHERE myid = $myid"
```

This query won't fail unless there is a syntax error, and you will get one row you need to fetch with one column returned which is your count.